# SQL Server 2008: Creating dynamic column names

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, dynamic, pivot, pivot-table

I have a problem that I cannot solve. I work on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and I have a table with four columns

```
Id
Date (2013-07, 2013-08, 2011-03, etc)
Amount 1 (100, 150, etc.) 
Amount 2 (100, 80, etc.)
```

If `Amount 1 > 150` then I need to create new columns with the values in `Date` as column names and distribute `Amount 2` into 6 (date) periods starting one month after the `Date` value.

It should look like this:

```
      Id  Date      Amount 1  Amount 2
      ----------------------------------
      1   2013-07    160         60
      2   2013-10    180         80                            

      Id  Date     Amount 1  2013-08  2013-09  2013-10   2013-11   2013-12  2014-01 ...
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1   2013-07    160         10       10      10         10        10      10
      2   2013-10    180                                     20        20      20...
```

I don't know how to do this and any help is highly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The table itself should not have these additional columns because that would be a denormalized table structure. That's a poor way to store data in many cases. But you can easily do a query against your existing table that will return the additional columns in the form you want, so that you can display it this way. Check out [PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx).

Comment: I am actually trying to do a query but I don't know how to dynamically return the column names. I have tried pivot and unpivot but I can't get it to work. Can you please give me an example? Thank you!